# Effect wording of Passive Skills in Mass Effect Andromeda

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

Did they deliberately make this confusing?

> Barrier (Biotic Passive), Rank 1:
>
> - Description: Maximum shield strength scales with each skill point invested in the Biotic Skill Group.
> - Effect: +5% Max Shields

The way it reads: "For every point put in Biotic Skills, you get an additional 5% to shields". . . that's what it looks like. Am I the only one that sees that? Cuz it sure as hell aint what happens.

Adding rank one took me from 340 to 353, which is more like 4% with an existing "21 points invested in skills" (quoted from the screen).

So nevermind the text, what are passives actually based on and how do they scale? I don't really care what the number actually is so long as the desc/text is clear and correct.

Comment: It might be possible that the effect number is the effective value you get, or maybe even an "up to X%" type value.

Comment: From what I've seen, the displayed percentage value for skill that scale is always the already calculated value, so in this case you get a total of 5% with the number of points you invested so far.

Comment: The numbers shown in the UI are the actual numbers as they stand right now with your skill investments. If the UI says +5%, you're getting +5%. Tested: checked my percentage, applied 20 unspent skill points, checked my percentage again

Answer (score 4):

Based on my own testing, it looks like you get 1% for each 6 points invested in the tree. As Mad Scientist pointed out, the value displayed is the total.

Since it's also additive with other boosters, you won't generally get 5% more than your current value.
For example, if you have +20% already from other sources, and then get a +5% from this, your original value of 300 is displayed as 360 from the other bonus. When you add this skill, it will go to 375. Since 5% of 300 is 15, you get that, rather than 5% of 360.

To specifically answer your question, I do not think they deliberately made it confusing.